# How to export separate excel sheet with datetime for each date in sqlserver 2008R2/ssis?

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, ssis

There are 2 tables called `table1` and `table2`.

I need to export the data based on condition

```
Table1

date         col2   col3   etc
2015-01-01    
2015-03-03
2015-02-27
```

columns needs to export from 412 columns

```
Table2
date    name    amount    ..... 276    
2015-01-01    
2015-02-01    
2015-02-04   
2015-02-02    
2015-02-15   
2015-02-24
```

Note :now I need to export the Excel sheet for matched date from `table1`.

Each Excel sheet should contain the records respective to that date because we do have >=1000 to 1 matching records for each date in `table1`.

The Excel sheet name should be `table name_2015-01-01.xlsx` so from the above table I have to export 3 Excel sheets.

kindly proivde one example either in ssis or bcp.

Comment: This is a broad topic.   Which part of it are you stuck on, exactly?

Comment: Thanks Alleman for reply . i have an brief idea by using while loop we may achieve it but i am not able to implement it so could you help me by posting SSIS packgae in zip format so that i can understand the developed package or code.

Comment: Write an SSIS package, zip it up and send it to you?   That's funny!   Try this google search:   "ssis export to multiple excel worksheets".    Good luck!

Comment: Dear Tab Alleman , If you don't know how to respond please stop it to answers someone's questions . do you think this blog is time pass one? and no one got answers or guidance to their questions ? please don't make this site is an argument site which is help full lot to lacks of IT professional .

Comment: This link has a decent pair of tutorials to get you started https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/88c331a8-38b2-4f49-b6d8-1768c310458b/export-query-result-to-multiple-excel-sheets-using-ssis , your question as is is a little too broad for this site, if you run into specific issues feel free to ask another question.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that you understand a little better what the community expects.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply finally i achieve my requirement with batch files

Answer (score 0):

First prepare the  required sql query results and make it in batch files

@Echo off
set datekey=%1

bcp "SELECT col1,'""' + ISNULL(col2,'') FROM tbalename WHERE DATE_KEY = %datekey%"  queryout path _%datekey%.csv -c -t, -r\n -S "servername" -U username -P pwd -d databasename

now we need to create the excel file individually with the tablename_date.csv /.xlsx

for that i have generated the exell sheet with required dates

bcp "select distinct date from table "  queryout path\filename.csv -c -t, -r\n -S "servername" -U username -P pwd -d databasename

now i need to keep the required dates in for loop  and call both individual batch file

set bfile="path\firstbatchfile.bat"
set refile="path\2ndbatchfile.bat"
call %refile% %%A
FOR /F %%A IN (2ndbatchfileoutput.txt) DO (
   call %bfile% %%A
)

now i will schedule the main batch file  that all.